# Prestashop 1.7.5 Cart cannot be loaded or an order has already been placed using this cart

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i have this error in prestashop 1.7.5, when a user pay (any payment method), the payment is made, but in the order confirmation page, I have a 500 error, the only information that i have is the log with the following message:

> Frontcontroller::init - Cart cannot be loaded or an order has already been placed using this cart

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I've been standing on this for a few days to launch my e-commerce,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can see this error only after order validation means payment done successfully and now cart is converted to the order. But, while redirecting to the order confirmation page you have some code/server error so you are seeing that 500 error. You should check error in the module which are transplanted to the displayOrderConfirmation hook.

Comment: In some Prestashop 1.6 versions the cart is not removed from the cookie after an order has been placed and next time the customer visits the webshop you get this error. In such cases the error is rather harmless. That is obviously not the case in this case but it is good to keep in mind for other people arriving on this page.

Answer (score 4):

In your case "Frontcontroller::init - Cart cannot be loaded or an order has already been placed using this cart" most likely triggered because [the condition in PaymentModule::validateOrder](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/PaymentModule.php#L256) is false. It can as well happen in the [FrontController](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/controller/FrontController.php#L362).

Anyways it comes from [Cart::orderExists method](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Cart.php#L1631). The reason cart is considered as existing can be unsynchronization of **ps_cart** and **ps_orders** tables. Try the following: run in mysql the following queries:

```
SELECT id_cart FROM ps_cart ORDER by id_cart DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT id_cart FROM ps_orders ORDER by id_cart DESC LIMIT 1;
```

To me the first was giving 345 while the second 1891, meaning AUTOINCREMENT value for **ps_cart** was set less then existing *id_cart* values in **ps_orders**. What makes a newly created cart quite a candidate to exist already in ps_orders.

So I simply increased the value of AUTOINCREMENT:

```
ALTER TABLE ps_cart AUTO_INCREMENT = 2000;
```

and it fixed the issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not a prestashop expert, so take this with a grain of salt. I think you maybe trying to create a new order with an older cart reference.

As in:

Order Id 1 tried to with Cart Id 1 reference : Successfully created order

Order Id 2 tried to create with Cart Id 1 reference : Failed

This is because I think an order must be associated with a unique cart. Take a look at the order schema by using the webservice, you'll notice a single reference to a cart.

Hope this helped.